# Specifying specific fields with Sequelize (NodeJS) instead of *

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Alright so I have a project in NodeJS where I'm utilizing Sequelize for a MySQL ORM. The thing works fantastically however I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to specify what fields are being returned on a query basis or if there's even a way just to do a .query() somewhere.

For example in our user database there can be ridiculous amounts of records and columns. In this case I need to return three columns only so it would be faster to get just those columns. However, Sequelize just queries the table for everything "*" to fulfill the full object model as much as possible. This is the functionality I'd like to bypass in this particular area of the application.

Comment: oh wow, there is now documentation about it :-/ lame. alessioalex is right.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You have to specify the attributes as a property in the object that you pass to findAll():

```
Project.findAll({attributes: ['name', 'age']}).on('success', function (projects) {
  console.log(projects);
});
```

How I found this:

The query is first called here: https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model-definition.js#L131 
Then gets constructed here: https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize/blob/master/lib/connectors/mysql/query-generator.js#L56-59

Comment: Hey can you please check the links, they seems to be broken

Answer (score 40):

Try this in **new** version

```
template.findAll({
    where: {
        user_id: req.params.user_id 
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'template_name'], 
}).then(function (list) {
    res.status(200).json(list);
})
```

Comment: I find this answer confusing. Why `attributes`, an array, says `//object`? Something similar occurs with `where`, it says `//array` but if looks like a single value (`number` or `string`).

Comment: @Camilo oops never mind, ignore the comment. it can be array, nested array or object. for more detail, you can have look https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html

Answer (score 19):

All Answers are correct but we can also use `include` and `exclude` as well

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: { include: ['id'] }
});

Model.findAll({
  attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt'] }
});
```

[Source](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Use the arrays in the attribute key. You can do nested arrays for aliases.

```
Project.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', ['name', 'project_name']],
  where: {id: req.params.id}
})
.then(function(projects) {
  res.json(projects);
})
```

Will yield:

```
SELECT id, name AS project_name FROM projects WHERE id = ...;
```