# Query to get all users id which has some property set to certain value - Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Is it possible with Sequelize to query db in order to get ids of all records which has certain property set to null?
The query below will get all users with updated_at property set to null, instead I'd like to get ids of these users.

```
  const users = await User.findAll({
    where: {
      updated_at: {
        [Op.ne]: null,
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: You can indicate only id attribute in **findAll** options and you'll get an array of users with one attribute only. Is it what you want?

Comment: @Anatoly is right, you have to declare an property in the object findAll at the same level as where, e.g attributes: ['id'] or attributes: ['name_attribute_1', 'name_attribute_2']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying specific fields with Sequelize (NodeJS) instead of \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039932/specifying-specific-fields-with-sequelize-nodejs-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

You can include attributes with a list of all column names that you need in the output.

```
  const users = await User.findAll({
    attributes: ["user_id"],
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    where: {
      updated_at: {
        [Op.ne]: null,
      },
    },
  });
```